# How to Send post data from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

this is my script

```
<?php
    $test= '121606901-hpe2';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 var url="getdata.php";
 var data={ no_hpe : <?php echo "'$test'"; ?> }
 var type="POST";
});

</script>
```

and getdata.php

```
$no_hpe=$_POST['no_hpe'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hpe_material where no_hpe='$no_hpe'";
```

but, my problem is `$no_hpe` is empty.how would I do this? thanks.

Comment: seeing as you're using jquery already, look at jquery ajax documentation - and actually try something

Comment: you seem to grasp the jquery ajax concept 2 years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601071/javascript-validation-save-data-to-mysql-not-working

Comment: you are just assigning data to var in js, you need to submit that data to server. you can do it using JQuery get, post or ajax functions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "getdata.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { no_hpe : <?php echo "'$test'"; ?> }
  }).done(function(resp) {
    // success
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus + " - Please try again.")
  })
```

This will send the data you want across to the php file using post

Answer (score 0):

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
url: 'mail.php',
type: 'POST',
data: formdata ,
success: function (response) {
        if(data.response === 'success') {
 alert(response);
}else{
alert(response);
}
},
});
```

This might be helps you